# How to rollback asyncpg transaction

Tags: transactions, asyncpg

Im using asyncpg to exec outer sql code (small and inner migration system). So in case of error in sql code I want to rollback all the DB changes in current transaction. But I cannot get transaction object to call rollback(). Please help!

My code is:

```
async with conn.transaction():
    try:
        await conn.execute(script)
    except asyncpg.exceptions.PostgresSyntaxError:
        logger('Got exception!')
        # what i have to write here to call rollback!?
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of `async with conn.transaction():` section transaction rolls back automatically if exception occurred there.

But you can control flow manually:

```
tr = conn.transaction()

try: 
    await tr.start() 
    await conn.execute('WRONG SQL STATEMENT / DO INTEGRITY ERROR HERE') 
except Exception as e:
    logger.error('Got exception {}', e)
    await tr.rollback()
else:
    tr.commit()
```

Comment: tr.commit() should have an await in front of it per docs `await tr.commit()`: https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html?highlight=cursor#transactions